# Eclipse UI issue on openSUSE with KDE

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, opensuse, kde-plasma

in my office I'm running

Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 (Build id: 20130225-0426) on

openSUSE 12.3 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12.3
CODENAME = Dartmouth

and have the following problem:

**Issue:**

I'm not able to see, if a button in the eclipse menu bars is clicked or not (e.g. the console lock button). The menu bar icon are also not changing on mouse over.

For example in the following screenshot from my eclipse the console lock is enabled:

[image]

**What I expect:**

Buttons which are click (enabled) should be displayed as clicked/enabled (like in Eclipse on my private Computer) 
On my colleagues computer, running same openSUSE, same Eclipse and same Default theme everything is working as expected.

**What I've already tried:**

- Installed latest Eclipse Kepler SR1
- changed to another openSUSE theme
- changed Eclipse colors (General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a similar issue with eclipse-kepler and opensuse 13.1. My mouse clicks do not work properly on package-explorer or similar views. Might be related.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this strange behaviour, but after googling a little bit I've found this old bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18933.

Try to start eclipse with the following args:

```
eclipse -vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already switched to Ubuntu and have no such issues anymore :)